# How can I fix this "Cannot create property text on String" error?

Tags: flash-cs5

I have 3 dynamic texts (h1,h2,h3) but I can't seem to do this:

```
var n:Array=["n1","n2","n3"];

for(var i = 0;i < 3; i++){
    n[i].text="hello";
}
```

This code gives me the error "Cannot create property text on String."

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting this error is because the array n contains 3 strings (n1, n2 and n3). So when you say: n[i].text, you are trying to set a non-existent property on a string.

If h1, h2 and h3 are the instance names of your text boxes, in your loop use this instead:

```
this["h"+i+1].text = "hello";
```

This code will reference the h1, h2 and h3 text boxes now. The reason there is a +1 added to i is because you are starting at 0, yet your first text box has a 1.

Comment: mm sorry the compiler say undefined

Comment: @Mayoo in this context is h1 a local variable or global? How would you access it normally?

Comment: Can you also post the error? This code worked for me, I just created 3 text boxes and named them h1, h2 and h3. Then put the code in the main timeline.

Answer (score 0):

A Fix:

```
this["t"+(i+1)].text = "j";
```